# Does the streamline at the top of the wing have the same curvature as the curve at the top of the wing? What does the difference mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

As shown in the figure, my question is that Curve A (Wing Top Curve) and Curve B (Streamline) are not equidistant curves. Why is this, and what does it mean for lift generation?

[image: streamline and wing]

Comment: Which streamline are you referring to? If you mean the layer of air absolutely  nearest the wing, theoretically friction stops its movement, so it should be the same shape as the wing,, but in practice, no streamline follows the curve of the wing exactly.

Comment: @StudyStudy Why doesn't it follow the wing curve?

Comment: Are you asking why Curve B is not parallel to Curve A?

Comment: @D.Halsey It can also be understood in this way.

Comment: The variation of the distance between streamlines A & B just tells you that the flow speed is changing in the chordwise direction. The relevant thing for lift is that the  streamlines above the wing are closer together (on average) than those below it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the angle of attack,the air meeting the leading edge of the wing is lifted away from the upper surface of the wing,causing a partial vacuum (low pressure) to form. Together with the high pressure below the wing,this is what gives the aerofoil lift.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like leading-edge separation, which is one of the ways that wings stall, and lose lift (except for vortex-lift from sharp leading edges). It is not a good description of the basic mechanism of a wing's lift.

Comment: Wings lift because of low pressure above and high pressure below. There's no getting away from it.  It may not be a good description, but it's an accurate description.

Comment: @ Michael Walsby I was referring to your statement that "the air meeting the leading edge of the wing is lifted away from the upper surface of the wing", when in fact the air follows the surface very closely.

Comment: So the streamline can't be equidistant from the curve of the wing, otherwise there will be no lift?

Comment: @D.Halsey It is not the air that leaves the wing along the normal direction, but the volume of the air increases along the normal direction, so the pressure on the top of the wing decreases.

Comment: It's a wonder nobody has come up with the old argument that lift is caused by the air flow speeding up over the top of the wing . So it does,but these are just two ways of describing the same phenomenon,both are correct. Whatever way you slice it, you can't get away from the fact that lift is caused by higher pressure below the wing than above it.

Comment: @ Michael Walsby Nobody is disputing the role of the pressure differences. But the motion of the air is along the streamlines. Your statement that it is "lifted away from the surface" is incorrect.

Comment: @enbin zheng When the streamlines get closer together, that indicates the flow speed is higher & the pressure is lower. It doesn't really make sense to say "the volume of the air increases along the normal direction"

Comment: If you had a smoke trail in a  wind tunnel when the airflow was  at very low speed,it would follow the wing surface more exactly,but as speed increased you would see it lifting away from the surface and following a line similar to B. At a great enough angle of attack,vortices would form.

Comment: @ Michael Walsby You have it backwards. High speed (or more precisely high Reynolds number)  makes it easier to keep the flow attached. The streamlines shown in the OP's diagram look like inviscid streamlines (essentially infinite Reynolds number), and there is no need to bring up flow separation in answering this question.

Comment: @D.Halsey The direction of velocity is not perpendicular to the normal direction. So there is a tendency to leave or approach along the normal direction. Is that the truth?

Comment: @enbin zheng The normal component of the velocity at the surface is zero. In viscous flows, so is the tangential component, but I believe we're discussing inviscid flows (where the streamlines are lines of constant streamfunction). In that case, the velocity at the surface is exactly perpendicular to the normal vector of the geometry. In some cases, viscous/inviscid interactions are modeled using a non-zero normal velocity component, but I don't think those cases are relevant to the explanation of the streamline shapes in your diagram.

Comment: @D.Halsey Is there a trend towards normal motion?

Comment: @enbin zheng  I think we've exceeded our quota of comments & it would probably help you more to just go study any basic aerodynamics text.

Comment: @D.Halsey I know the limitation of comment, so is there a trend of moving along the normal direction?!